SSLVerificationFailed when initializing airflowctl
I am trying to install airflowctl to enable testing of Dags locally. However when i am trying to run command in my vs code "airflowctl init my_airflow_project --build-start" it gives me error stating
"SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get   
local issuer certificate

I have tried setting up root_ca_bundle in my environment variable and also tried using win-ca plugin in append mode but nothing has helped me yet.
Any suggestions?
